# Flex 4 and Actionscript 3 creating form elements based on number of items selected

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, forms, list

So I have a list control that i set to allowMultipleSelection...essentially what i am trying to do is have a form that created a text input for every item i have selected in my list...i have it kind of working so when i select the first item it added the form input, but when i select the second item it adds two form inputs and keeps the first form input, making three total...obviously instead of just adding them, i just want it to be updated, i am also confused on how i would handle deselecting an item and updating the form...here's my code and thanks for any help in advance.

```
protected function multipleFormulaListChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
            var numberSelected:uint = multFormulaList.selectedItems.length;
            trace(numberSelected);
            for(var i:int = 0; i < numberSelected; i++) {
                var formitem:FormItem = new FormItem;
                var forminput:TextInput = new TextInput;
                formitem.addElement(forminput);
                theform.addElement(formitem);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great results using [mx.collections.ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html) and [mx.collection.IViewCursor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IViewCursor.html) for situations like these.

Using an ArrayCollection (which is essentially an associative array) you could keep track of what items are currently selected by storing the items themselves:

```
private var currSelected:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

protected function multipleFormulaListChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var numberSelected:uint = multFormulaList.selectedItems.length;
    for each(var item:Object in multFormulaList.selectedItems) {
        //add item to currSelected AC
        currSelected.addItem(item);
    }
}
```

To prevent the introduction of duplicates and the entire reason for even mentioning cursors or array collections in the first place -- you would also create a view cursor on what is now your selected items array collection and utilize that cursor's findAny() method (to prevent further looping )to ascertain an item's existence in your selected items array collection.  Set up in conditional form within the loop you've got going currently you'd get something like this:

```
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.collections.IViewCursor;

import mx.collections.Sort;
import mx.collections.SortField;

private var currSelected:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
//Be sure to run a sort on currSelected because cursors can only be created on sorted array collections
/*
    var sort:Sort = new Sort();
    sort.fields = [new SortField(null, true)];
    currSelected.sort = sort;

*/

protected function multipleFormulaListChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
    //create cursor 
    var cursor:IViewCursor = currSelected.createCursor();
    //loop through selected items list comparing each looped item with the currSelected array for matches
    for each(var item:Object in multFormulaList.selectedItems) {
        if(!cursor.findAny(item)){
            //no match found - add item to currSelected AC and create form field 
            currSelected.addItem(item);
            //for add logic
            var formitem:FormItem = new FormItem;
            var forminput:TextInput = new TextInput;
            formitem.addElement(forminput);
            theform.addElement(formitem);
        }else{
            //match found - not adding
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is great, thanks! i do have 2 questions though, how would i remove an item from the currSelected array by clicking on an already selected item which then would remove that associated form item? Also the original data for the list is coming from an array collection that is populated from xml and i am experiencing issues transferring the data from the original arraycollection to the new currSelected array collection..how can i handle this? thanks a lot you are a huge help

Answer (score 0):

If your items are known, it may be better to handle this via the visible and includeInLayout properties of your form items.

However, if you want complete dynamism, I would keep an associative array (an Object) where you store which items have already been included in your form. Your event should check against this object before creating and adding them again.

When you unselect an element, just remove it from your form and delete it from your associative array object.

Let's say your associative array is called `alreadyShown`. The only thing you need to do inside your code is:

```
if(alreadyShown[idOfTheItemYouWantToAdd]!=1){
  /*
  paste the code that adds your item here
  */
  alreadyShown[idOfTheItemYouWantToAdd] = 1
}
```

When you remove your item, you should set `alreadyShown[idOfTheItemYouWantToAdd]` to 0

Comment: i have thought about the visible and includeInLayout properties but with a list of over 200 items i dont think it will work, if you could point me in a direction of using an associative array to do something like this that would be extremely helpful...thanks for your response!